# ngx-scrollbar doesn't work well with mat-dialog-content

Tags: angular, angular-material, scrollbar, angular7

I am using [ngx-scrollbar](https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-scrollbar/) for all scrollbars inside my application.
However, it doesn't work well with mat-dialog-content.

With the below code, the ngx-scrollbar doesn't display.

```
<div class="dialog-header">
  <h4>Header Here</h4>
</div>

<mat-dialog-content>
    <ng-scrollbar>
        {{ contents.here }}
    </ng-scrollbar>
<mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
 ... some buttons here
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

This is the generated HTML code after serving the angular files:
[image]